# AWS loadbalancer requires an @ cname record but this overrides my @ MX records

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, cname, mx-record

I need to add a CName record for my load-balanced AWS site mywebsite.com. The record should be:

```
@   CNAME           mywebsite.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

However it appears (according to 123-reg) that this would override the @ MX records I have for email to this domain:

```
@   MX  300     mail1.mywebsite.com.
@   MX  400     mail2.mywebsite.com.
@   MX  500     mail3.mywebsite.com.
```

I'm stumped because both of these look sensible and I did not expect that the CName would take precedence over the MX in this way.

Any ideas on how to proceed? I figure there must be another way to setup the MX records, but not sure how.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend that you move your DNS hosting to Amazon Route 53.

You won't be able to use a `CNAME` there either, as this is a general DNS restriction (see RFC 1034 section 3.6.2 - http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html).  However, for `A` Records at Route 53, you can specify that the record is an "Alias" (this is a special AWS feature), and pick your ELB as the target, instead of a specific IP address.  Because the host is configured via and A record, you should be able to enter the `MX` records as well.

In addition, Route 53 is a very advanced DNS system, and affordable, with pricing starting at under a dollar a month (http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/), so you will be getting a lot of other benefits as well.

Comment: If you use `Route 53` do you need to transfer your domain name from your current provider (e.g. 1&1) to AWS? The issue I have with that is AWS's pricing seems ridiculous for domain names.  i.e. $50/month plus other costs https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/. Or am I reading their pricing incorrectly?

Comment: Your domain name does not need to be transferred to AWS, you can keep it with your current provider (1&1) but you'll need to update the nameserver config at 1&1 to utilize the Route 53 nameservers. 

RE: pricing.  "Pricing for domain names varies by TLD."  `.com` is currently priced at $12 for the Registration and Renewal Price (see the Domain Names section, here: [Amazon Route 53 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/)).

Answer (score 1):

yes even I had same problem after switching to Route 53 this was solved. When it comes to pricing Route 53 is not expensive at all, its like paying for peanuts if you have production system running on AWS and already spending a lot.